# How can I switch audio output from A2DP to jack?

Tags: bluetooth, audio

is it possible to switch A2DP audio streaming to jack output without turning off bluetooth completely? Didn't find any option.

**Edit:** The question is: Is it possible to toggle it within the software without plugging in or out a cable and so on? Sorry if this question has caused some confusions.

Is it hidden or just impossible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When A2DP connects it tells the phone to transmit audio via bluetooth (except while watching video, dont ask... been palm-faceplanting over that one). In my car (A2DP bluetooth enabled) I was able to send audio to my headphone jack (watching Netflix... "in traffic"), yet the stereo was still able to answer phone calls via bluetooth.

I dont know if that would work in your situation, but have someone call you while connected to bluetooth and listening to music via 3.5mm jack.

Comment: So this means I have no option to manually toggle it. Thank you. :)

Comment: No, currently there isn't a way to toggle it on and off =(

Answer (score 1):

On my Omnia 7 I can just plug in a jack while music is playing thru the bluetooth and my phone will automatically switch to playing via the jack. I assume all WP will work that way.

Comment: Thank you for that information. But as I edited my question above I meant to ask if there is a button to toggle it manually without plugging in or out the audio jack.